# Fitting linear regression with correlational data

Tags: regression, logistic, panel-data

I'm investigating what are the differences of certain dichotomous variables (such as "felt tired" or "had a near-miss accident") between shift types in a sample of shift workers. Shift type is categorical (Morning, Day, Evening). The shifts occur irregularly in the data and not all workers had all types of shifts. The study period was a few weeks, so all drivers worked most types of shifts more than once. Of course they also had days off. The sequence of shift types was different for most workers.

Importantly, I assume interindividual variability in e.g. the propensity to be tired at work, so simple comparisons of shift types in terms of these variables of interest is not the way to approach this. I'm thinking Generalised Estimating Equations would be more fitting, however, I'm unsure of how to carry it out in R or SPSS.

My data is in the following format (all variables of interest and days off not included):

```
ID   Shift   Tired

1   M   0
1   M   1
1   M   0
1   D   0
1   E   1
1   E   0
1   M   0
1   M   1
...
21   E   0
21   M   0
21   D   1
```

Comment: It looks like you need to run a logistic regression. You seem to be aware of this based on your tags even though the question title doesn't reflect this. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: It is assumed that e.g. tiredness at work is related to individual factors as well as shift characteristics. My data violates the requirement of logistic regression that observations should be independent of each other. I'm looking for a method that allows this dependency, and the fact that the amount of shifts of different types is unbalanced between workers, and most shift types occur more than once in most workers.

Comment: 1) This is information that you should edit into your question, because not everyone reads the comments. 2) Have you quantified how bad the multicollinearity problem is? It need not negate the logistic regression approach. 3) Your title is misleading and you are more likely to receive good answers if you edit it to reflect your problem.

Answer (score 2):

To estimate the associations between variables in a study containing repeated measurements (in this case shifts within the same driver), you should use methods which account for dependent data. The generalized estimating equation model (GEE) is a powerful tool for program evaluation and epidemiology because it estimates a population averaged effect. Packages which fit GEEs in R are `gee` and `geese`. Load the library and call the help file for information on fitting the models `library(gee)`, and `?gee`.

Comment: That's a good, sophisticated suggestion. My comment would be for the OP to test several models with each model representing an increment in the # of parameters and control wrt dependence. The objective is to see how increasing complexity reduces the error and/or improves the explanatory power and inference(s). Start with a baseline linear ANOVA that included shift and driver as factors then,  to control for the dependence you've noted, repeated measures ANOVA followed by a GEE or a hierarchical model.  As appropriate,  introduce additional predictors mentioned but not specified in the query.

Comment: @DJohnson I might differ with you in terms of approach here. The objective of the analysis in question is to assess the relationship with several risk factors and possible adverse events. Model building based on fitting several models increases the risk of various type I errors driven by artifacts of data rather than *a priori* hypotheses. Model building based on the latter is well warranted. I do agree other possible confounders should be included such as driver age, experience, and number of previous incidents.

Comment: The models should be independent, no? If that's true how would there be any increased risk of type I error?

Comment: @DJohnson Model building as you describe is very much dependent because your choice to look at later models (and decide which one is ultimately used for inference) is very much based on what the previous models showed you.

Comment: I don't agree. Your comment would make sense if the models were somehow nested. They are not. The only thing changing is the framework or engine underlying the inputs.

Comment: @DJohnson this might spark some good discussion if you can formulate it in a manner appropriate for a CV question. Alternately you can contribute your own answer to the OP's question. Ultimately, I take the stance that the point of data analysis in this question is to confirm a hypothesis, and that different models correspond to different hypotheses, so while your approach would be okay for a post-hoc analysis, the answer to the question lies in specifying a robust, interpretable model *apriori*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My view is that we're coming at the OPs query from different perspectives. Your assumption appears to be one of *a priori* formal hypothesis-testing and inference within a pre-determined theoretical framework whereas my assumption is *a priori* exploratory using fixed inputs to build up  from the simplest linear model (ANOVA) to increasing levels of model complexity and sophistication. In your case the model (functional form) is given, in my case the model is to be discovered. Only the OP can judge which approach is more suited to his purposes.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using package geeM in R. I used dummy variables MORNING and EVENING, which would be 1 for corresponding shift types. This way day shifts would be used as a reference. In R, I got it to work using call geem(Tired~MORNING+EVENING,ID,data=dataname,family=binomial("logit")).